# Error in the execution of pip install pyaudio on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: python, macos, pyaudio

> `Collecting pyaudio
>     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
>     Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
>     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>      command: /anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-_jk8c3tj/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-_jk8c3tj/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/tmp/pip-wheel-ze2dwvn0 --python-tag cp36
>          cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-_jk8c3tj/pyaudio/
>     Complete output (16 lines):
>     running bdist_wheel
>     running build
>     running build_py
>     creating build
>     creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
>     copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
>     running build_ext
>     building '_portaudio' extension
>     creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
>     creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src
>     gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DMACOSX=1 -I/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
>     src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
>     #include "portaudio.h"
>              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     1 error generated.
>     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`
>
> ---
>
> `ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
>     Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
>   Failed to build pyaudio
>   Installing collected packages: pyaudio
>       Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
>       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>        command: /anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-_jk8c3tj/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-_jk8c3tj/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-a_zim1cg/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
>            cwd: /private/tmp/pip-install-_jk8c3tj/pyaudio/
>       Complete output (16 lines):
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
>       copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
>       running build_ext
>       building '_portaudio' extension
>       creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
>       creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src
>       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DMACOSX=1 -I/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
>       src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
>       #include "portaudio.h"
>                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       1 error generated.
>       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>       ----------------------------------------
>   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-_jk8c3tj/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-_jk8c3tj/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-a_zim1cg/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: Which version of python are you using? And are you using the mac installed python?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming and belongs on Ask Different site.

Comment: @C.Nivs Python 3.6

Comment: @C.Nivs https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell I got the solution through creating my own virtual environment wherein I was able to install it and run al of it's functionalities